# How long should it take for my beer to clear?

Tags: clarity, finings

I'm not new to wine making (many, many years) and have been making beer for only a few years, generally gelatin fining with bottle conditioning and having good results. Clear beer, good flavor, head, etc.

I just made a Session IPA, it started at 1.050 and finished at 1.015, within the recommended range.  After seeing some posts and videos on line, I decided to try Super Kleer vs Gelatin for fining (use it for wine with great success), on this batch of beer.  After two days very little if any change in clarity, but I have a large yeast cake (and probably SK at the bottom of the carboy).  I moved it into a refrigerator to cold crash it a bit to see if that would help, alas four days now and no real change in clarity.

I don't know if I screwed something up or not, no Irish Moss or other additive used during the boil.  Vigorous boil, quick cool down, very active fermentation.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, need a little help getting though this learning curve.

Answer (score 1):

Most finings work in 48 hours along with a cold crash of 34-38°F

Super Kleer is a two stage fining product. Meaning two different additions at different times.

Assuming it was properly used I would review your beer recipe for adjuncts that do not clairify well. Oats, wheat, citrus oils etc.

It's still ok to use gelitan and cold crash to try to fine this batch further.

Comment: Ok, added gelatin and cold crashed. After 3 days no change. Have been away for a few more and will check again tomorrow.  Assuming its still not clear, what options do I have to salvage this beer?

Comment: @Quentin it's just appearances, cloudy beers are becoming popular actually.  There could be haze that can't be cleared from certain grains, mash temps etc. If it tastes good I wouldn't worry about it. Sometimes a wild can haze a beer, but then it wouldn't taste that great.

Comment: Thanks, beer not clear, but no particulates floating around in it. Big trub at bottom. Racked it to kegs we'll see in a few days if its drinkable...smells good though, fingers crossed.

Comment: Beer kegged, quite good, it looks like I made a fashionable, unflitered IPA.  I have written the kit company, we'll see if they have any insight, and I'll post their comments.

Comment: The kit company responded today, recommended that in the future I move the beer to a secondary, just before fermentation is competed, and following a 2 week period I should have clear beer without any finings added.  Whilfloc was mentioned for IPA's or beers that would have significant trub.  We'll see how those recommendations pan out.